# Use of static init block

Tags: java, static-initializer

I know how a static init block works.
Can anyone please tell me some typical uses of it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you want to initialize one or more static variables in one place

It is useful, because you can apply exception handling, which is not possible with the in-line initialization.

For example:

```
public static ImageIcon defaultIcon = ImageIO.read(..);
```

can be initialized with

```
public static ImageIcon defaultIcon;
static {
   try {
       defaultIcon = ImageIO.read(..);
   } catch (IOException ex){
     System.out.println("No default icon available");
   }
}
```

Another application is complex initialization. For example, if an item requires more than one line of code to be initialized. Let's say you have a configuration:

```
public static Configuration configuration;
static {
     confuguration = new Configuration();
     configuration.setSomething(..);
     configuration.setSomethingElse(..);
     ...
}
```

A third usage is to initialize some external API infrastructure. One example from my current project:

```
static {
    org.apache.xml.security.Init.init();
}
```

But, as Mykola Golubyev noted, static initialization blocks make code less readable, so use them with caution. static methods do the same thing more transparently.

Comment: If which class do you use your example with "security.Init.init()"?

Comment: It is required by the API. See http://santuario.apache.org/Java/api/org/apache/xml/security/Init.html

Answer (score 5):

Just try to avoid use of static initialization block. Instead you can use private static initialization functions which will make your code more clean.

I will refer to @Bozho for examples.

Do not do

```
public static Configuration configuration;
static {
     confuguration = new Configuration();
     configuration.setSomething(..);
     configuration.setSomethingElse(..);
     ...
}
```

Use instead

```
public static Configuration configuration = createConfiguration();
```

or

```
public static Configuration configuration = YourConfiguration.create();
```

Comment: Agreed. Use a block as stated above creates serious issues with unit testing.

Answer (score 3):

They're often used in conjunction with [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) code to ensure that the required native library is loaded:

```
class MyJniConnection {

    public static native void myJniCall();

    static {
        System.load("native.dll");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- Initializing a collection static
  field, like Map, List, Set, etc
- Initializing setter-based object which is also static

Answer (score 2):

#### JDBC Driver Is a Popular Example

Why do you need `Class.forName()` to load a driver into memory. The answer is simple. As stipulated in the JDBC specs, all JDBC `Driver` have a static block to register themselves with `DriverManager` as soon as the `Driver` class is loaded. Something like this:

```
static {
    try {
        java.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver(new Driver());
    } catch (SQLException E) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Can't register driver!");
    }
}
```

So, when you write (for example with the MySQL driver here):

```
Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver");
```

The classloader attempts to load and link the `org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver` class and, if successful, the static initialization block gets executed and the `Driver` registers itself with the `DriverManager`.

Answer (score 1):

They can be used to create a DSL, as JMock does. For instance, to set an expectation that a user will be saved to the database:

```
Mockery context = new Mockery();
final Database database = context.mock(Database.class);    
...
context.checking(new Expectations() {{
    oneOf(database).save(user);
}});

// Rest of the test
```

Answer (score 0):

- static block :- when we want to execute code at the time of loading of class then we can put the code in static block...
- init :- when we want to execute code at the time of initiated of object of a class then we can put the code in init block....